# Redirect from a front end server to back end one

Tags: reactjs, api, redirect, hyperlink, router

first of all I deleted a bunch of unnecessary code from here, just to point out the problem.
So I run a frontend server on port 3000 and a backend one on 3002. On the front end I want to log in via google authentification, but It runs on the back end and I don't really know how to access it. The try below is the best I've had so far, but when I click the link nothing loads, even though when I hover the link It is the one I need. Also, the authentification works in the back end, but no link would load from this code.

The route I'm on when trying this is http://localhost:3000/play/instructions, and if I change the line <Link button href={`${API}/login`}> to something like <Link button href={`test`}> it would redirect to localhost:3000/test, which WOULD load, but why does it not load for my attepmpt?

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
    
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { Link as RouteLink } from "react-router-dom"; // TODO: routing links
import { Link } from "@material-ui/core";

const API = "localhost:3002";

const QuizInstructions = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <Helmet>
      <title>Exam Instructions</title>
    </Helmet>
    <div className="instructions container">
      <br />
      <div>
        <span className="left">
          <RouteLink to="/">Go back to the Home Page</RouteLink>
        </span>
        <span className="right">
          <Link button href={`${API}/login`}>
            Start exam
          </Link>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
);

export default QuizInstructions;
```

Comment: If you are going to a different hostname, you will at least need that url to start with `http` or `https`

Comment: It's still one on the localhost, just a different port, can I not do it like this?

Comment: I should have said 'origin' not 'hostname', but same comment otherwise. You could also start with `\\` to do retain the scheme you are on.